# How would you get turtle to overlap certain areas of squares?

Tags: python, recursion, draw

So I had to get familiar with turtle for a project with school. I got basically everything my professor asked besides for overlapping the squares. [image: My squares]

However he would like the squares to overlap like this

[image: Profsquares]

I haven't been able to replicate this at all. I am wondering if their is something I need to throw into my code to easily solve it.

Here is my code

```
import turtle #Imports the 'turtle module' which allows intricate shapes and pictures to be drawn
my_turtle_pos = (10 , 10)
def square(my_turtle,x,y,length) : #I set up a function that helps me determine the square

    my_turtle.penup() #Picks 'up' the turtle pen
    my_turtle.setposition(x-length/2,y-length/2) #Helps set positon
    my_turtle.pendown() #Puts 'down' the turtle pen
    my_turtle.color('black','red') #Allows black outline, with red filling
    my_turtle.begin_fill() #Starts the filling of red and helps remember the starting point for a filled area
    my_turtle.forward(length) #Moves the turtle by the specified amount 'length'
    my_turtle.left(90) #Moves the turtle by given amount '90'
    my_turtle.forward(length)
    my_turtle.left(90)
    my_turtle.forward(length)
    my_turtle.left(90)
    my_turtle.forward(length)
    my_turtle.left(90)
    my_turtle.end_fill() #Stops filling with red, which will close with the current color

def graphic_pattern(my_turtle,x,y,length,times): #recursive function
    if times <= 0:  #This just tells us how many 'times' it needs to repeat till given amount
        return
    newSize = length/2.2 #This will grab the new size
    graphic_pattern(my_turtle,x-length/2,y-length/2,newSize,times-1) #Functions to help with writing 'smaller' squares
    graphic_pattern(my_turtle,x-length/2,y+length/2,newSize,times-1)
    graphic_pattern(my_turtle,x+length/2,y-length/2,newSize,times-1)
    graphic_pattern(my_turtle,x+length/2,y+length/2,newSize,times-1)
    square(my_turtle,x,y,length)


my_turtle = turtle.Turtle(shape="arrow") #You can use differen't shapes for the turtle, I chose arrow, though the turtle was cool :)
my_turtle.speed(100) #I am not sure how fast the turtle can go, I just chose 100 cause it went by quicker.

graphic_pattern(my_turtle,3,0,300,4) #Example pattern stated from homework assignment.
```

I think it's something to do with where the pen draws the squares first. Thanks for any input!

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please [mark it as 'accepted’](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like it's a simple sequencing of your `graphic_pattern()` and `square()` methods. It seems you would want to draw the top right `graphic_pattern()` first, followed by the middle square, and then followed by the rest of the `graphic_pattern()` calls:

```
import turtle #Imports the 'turtle module' which allows intricate shapes and pictures to be drawn
my_turtle_pos = (10 , 10)
def square(my_turtle,x,y,length) : #I set up a function that helps me determine the square

    my_turtle.penup() #Picks 'up' the turtle pen
    my_turtle.setposition(x-length/2,y-length/2) #Helps set positon
    my_turtle.pendown() #Puts 'down' the turtle pen
    my_turtle.color('black','red') #Allows black outline, with red filling
    my_turtle.begin_fill() #Starts the filling of red and helps remember the starting point for a filled area
    my_turtle.forward(length) #Moves the turtle by the specified amount 'length'
    my_turtle.left(90) #Moves the turtle by given amount '90'
    my_turtle.forward(length)
    my_turtle.left(90)
    my_turtle.forward(length)
    my_turtle.left(90)
    my_turtle.forward(length)
    my_turtle.left(90)
    my_turtle.end_fill() #Stops filling with red, which will close with the current color

def graphic_pattern(my_turtle,x,y,length,times): #recursive function
    if times <= 0:  #This just tells us how many 'times' it needs to repeat till given amount
        return
    newSize = length/2.2 #This will grab the new size

    graphic_pattern(my_turtle,x+length/2,y+length/2,newSize,times-1)
    square(my_turtle,x,y,length)
    graphic_pattern(my_turtle,x-length/2,y-length/2,newSize,times-1)
    graphic_pattern(my_turtle,x-length/2,y+length/2,newSize,times-1)
    graphic_pattern(my_turtle,x+length/2,y-length/2,newSize,times-1)


my_turtle = turtle.Turtle(shape="arrow") #You can use differen't shapes for the turtle, I chose arrow, though the turtle was cool :)
my_turtle.speed(100) #I am not sure how fast the turtle can go, I just chose 100 cause it went by quicker.

graphic_pattern(my_turtle,3,0,300,4) #Example pattern stated from homework assignment.
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the visit order of your recursive calls.

Now the order is post-order (visit all children, then visit the node).

With this particular order (visit upper right child, visit the node, visit the remaining children):

```
def graphic_pattern(my_turtle,x,y,length,times): #recursive function
    if times <= 0:  #This just tells us how many 'times' it needs to repeat till given amount
        return
    newSize = length/2.2 #This will grab the new size
    graphic_pattern(my_turtle,x+length/2,y+length/2,newSize,times-1)
    square(my_turtle,x,y,length)
    graphic_pattern(my_turtle,x-length/2,y-length/2,newSize,times-1) #Functions to help with writing 'smaller' squares
    graphic_pattern(my_turtle,x-length/2,y+length/2,newSize,times-1)
    graphic_pattern(my_turtle,x+length/2,y-length/2,newSize,times-1)
```

you can obtain the desired pattern.